# Non-greedy wild card appears to match greedily?

Tags: python, search, greedy

I need to understand why regular expression is matching greedily when I am specifying it not to.

Given `string='.GATA..GATA..ETS..ETS.'`

Return the shortest substring of GATA...ETS

I use the regex pattern `pattern = r'(GATA).*?(ETS)'`

```
syntax_finder=re.compile(pattern,re.IGNORECASE)

for match in syntax_finder.finditer(string):
    print(match)
```

Returns `<re.Match object; span=(1, 17), match='GATA..GATA..ETS'>`

However, I want it to return `'GATA..ETS'`

Does anyone know why this is happening?

I am not looking for a solution to this exact matching problem. I will be doing a lot of these types of searches with more complicated patterns of GATA and ETS, but I will always want it to return the shortest match.

Thanks!

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) says _"The `'*'`, `'+'`, and `'?'` qualifiers are all greedy; they match as much text as possible"_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anyone know why this is happening?

The regex matches non-greedily. It finds the first `GATA` and then, because `.*?` is used rather than `.*`, matches until the *first* `ETS` after that. It just happens that there is another `GATA` in the way, which you don't want - but which non-greedy matching doesn't care about.

> I will be doing a lot of these types of searches with more complicated patterns of GATA and ETS

Then regexes are probably underpowered for the job. My suggestion is to use them to split the string into GATA, ETS and intervening portions (*tokenization*), and then use other techniques to find the patterns in that sequence (*parsing*).

> I am not looking for a solution to this exact matching problem.

But I can't resist :)

```
>>> re.search(r'(GATA)((?<!GAT)A|[^A])*?(ETS)', '.GATA..GATA..ETS..ETS.')
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(7, 16), match='GATA..ETS'>
```

Here we use a negative lookbehind assertion: while scanning the part between `GATA` and `ETS`, we only allow an `A` if it is not preceded by `GAT`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Karl! This was very helpful and I understand whats happening now. Yes, I agree. I think another approach is better suited.